# Terrasync COM Port Unavailable

Tags: gps, trimble

I have a Trimble GeoExplorer Series GeoXM that runs Windows PocketPC version 4.2 (Built March 15 2004 for a bit more resolution there).

Lately when the unit has been out on a job it will periodically disconnect from the internal GIS receiver (TISP on COM3) and give an error message that says:

```
"Failed to connect to the GPS receiver because the COM port in in use by another application"
```

My field techs tell me that this is happening randomly, sometimes several times a day.  So far the only way I have to deal with it is to tell them to just keep trying to connect and after a few tries (generally around 20 minutes of waiting) it comes back online and they carry on with their task.

This unit is used exclusively to run Terrasync (v3.01) - it doesn't do anything else so I don't understand what other program could be occupying the COM port when Terrasync needs it.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Terrasync and the problem has persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a brief stint with GPS/GIS tech support a while ago so I am a little rusty.  I do remember the Windows PocketPC's com ports getting hung up.  The problem was usually 1 of 3 things.

1. a compatibility issue with a combo of Terrasync, the OS on the GeoExplorer, GPS Pathfinder Office (data transfer utility) or Microsoft's Activesync.
2. Terrasync was installed to the Main Memory not the Disk
3. A reset was needed.

Issue 2 & 3 are explained in greater detail in this manual, page 22-24, http://www.geoplane.com/downloads/Datalogger_Manuals/Mapping/GeoExplorer%202003%20XT%20Getting%20Started%20Guide.pdf

Trimble has a Compatibilty Matrix Chart so you can verify you have the most up to date version, http://www.neigps.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Trimble-Compat-2013.pdf

Answer (score 2):

My GeoXT with Terrasync 2.53 did exactly the same thing. I began to suspect a "loose cable."

Popped the yellow plastic back off (six screws around the perimeter) and reseated the end of the ribbon cable coming from the GPS receiver (at the very top of the unit) to a PCB-turned-connector, about the size of a quarter, just near the top right edge of the battery pack. It mates with 3 metal pins...likely be Tx, Rx and GND!!!

Anyway, mate/unmate 3 x and it'll wipe the corrosion/crap off the pins, and VOILA! Connects to the GPS every time now!
Hope this helps.
Ned