# Trimble GeoXH Geoexplorer 2008 COM1 problem

Tags: error, geoexplorer, trimble, hardware

I am using TerraSync and getting an error:

> GPS: The COM port is already configured for use by another device.

Does anyone know how to correct this so I can start using my bluetooth connection again for logging information?

[image]

Comment: I've tangled with similar issues (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84066/terrasync-com-port-unavailable).  Maybe the links in the answer there will be helpful.

Comment: I've also had this issue.  9 times out 10 a soft reset will do the trick.  If you're bluetoothing to a receiver or antenna sometimes that connection will get hung up.  You will probably need to reestablish the bluetooth connection after the soft reset too.  http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-414997/MGIS_SprtNote_GeoExplr2008_Reset.pdf